# Wordpress - How to auto publish a blog with a poll everyday?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to have a plugin or something that would post one blog each day at specific time, which would contain only one poll and enable comments.

Imagine this,

- every day at 12.00AM a new blog post appears with the same poll everyday 
  "How is your day today?"
  a) good
  b) bad
- this poll can be modified by admin, and from then on the modified version is published daily
- users can vote only once per poll (probably by IP)
- users can add comments
- admin should be able to add other content as needed but poll-blogs should continue auto publishing

That's it. I'd like to have this completely on autopilot.

It doesn't have to be Wordpress it can be Tumblr or anything else that's out there, but a blog format would be most suitable.

Answer (score 1):

WP-Polls is a Wordpress Poll extension that you can schedule a polls to be added.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-polls/

Comment: so if I understand correctly, I would create the schedule with this same poll and repeat it to start every day? That would require quite a lot of manual entry but would essentially do the job.